# Should I nip flower buds to encourage rooting

Tags: grafting, rooting-hormone

I have dipped a few twigs from fruit trees (apple, cherry, peach) in a rooting hormone, and planted them in a small container.

The twigs have started flowering (two weeks after planting them). To encourage root growth, should i nip the flowering buds?

[image: Flowers 1]
[image]

======

Edit. A month later…

i unfortunately did not get the answers in time, and had to leave for a long trip. I did not trim the flowers nor trim the buds, but will certainly do so next time.

Only the two apple varieties I had seem to have survived. The other species died, from fungus it looks like. I placed them all under a plastic bag to create a mini greenhouse, and they probably didn’t receive enough airflow.

The apple trimmings have started growing mini leaves, hopefully to bootstrap their photosynthesis. But they’re looking pretty weak.

[image: little leaves growing]

Answer (score 3):

**Important**: I have zero experience with trees, all of the below is based on rooting of Pelargonium(a flower) cuttings. Regard everything as a comment instead of an answer to go by!!!

---

Yes.

Flowering seems to draw incredible amounts of energy. My success rate for rooting non-flowering cuttings is about 25% and for flowering: 0% <sub>(n1 ~= 30, n2 ~= 5)</sub>.

Flowering requires some [Potassium](https://ptable.com/?lang=en#Properties) but that's beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 2):

For travellers arriving here in the future.

Flowering does require an immense amount of energy.

It's always a good idea to think about the time of year you take your cuttings to avoid them flowering (Winter or very early spring for apples).

When we've been transplanting cuttings we generally always soak the base in willow water for a few days and then continue to water them with it every other day when they're in the soil.

I *think* (although I have no evidence, so correct me if I'm wrong) that the rooting hormones in the willow water encourage the plant to put it's energy into rooting instead of flowering, that coupled with the correct timing (see above) should ensure you have strong enough saplings to be planted out by the following spring.

Comment: +1 Today's local gardening newspaper says just the above! Rough translation: "Remove the flower buds of trees moved in autumn as producing fruit draws incredible amount of energy."